# How to render html from string in angular2 using html agility pack?

Tags: html, angular

I am using Angular 4. I am facing an issue to render HTML (with CSS) from  a text string.  Is it possible via Html Agility pack?. If yes, how can I use that? Can you provide a sample being used in Angular -2 or Angular-4?.

I had used innerHtml property as well but it is not displaying Css styles.

My Code Snippet:

**x.component.ts:**

```html
private _messageText: string="<html><body><p><b>This text is bold</b></p><p><i>This text is italic</i></p></body></html>";
```

**x.html:**

```html
<div class="textarea-preview" [innerHTML]="_messageText"></div>
```

**x.css**

```css
.textarea-preview 
{
    
width: 100%;
 
border: none;
 
pointer-events: none;
   
background-color: transparent;
 
resize: none;
 
outline: none;
  
font-size: 1rem;
 
-webkit-appearance: none;
  
overflow-x: hidden;
  
overflow-y: hidden;

}
```

Output is:

```html
This text is bold
This text is italic
```

**Desired output:**

```html
"This text is bold" must be in bold as we are using <b></b> tag here.
"This text is italic" must be in italic as we are using <i></i> tag here.
but it is displaying in simple text format not displaying style tags and css.
```

Comment: Please provide the code-snippets of what you have tried.

Comment: doesnt a simple `$('mydiv').innerHTML = "yourstring";` work ?

Comment: x.component.ts:
 private _messageText: string="<html><body><p><b>This text is bold</b></p><p><i>This text is italic</i></p></body></html>"; 

x.html:
<div class="textarea-preview" [innerHTML]="_messageText"></div>

Output is:
This text is bold
This text is italic


Desired output:
"This text is bold" must be in bold as we are using <b></b> tag here.
"This text is italic" must be in italic as we are using <i></i> tag here.
but it is displying in simple text format not displaying style tags and css.

Comment: I have provided required code-snippet in above comment where I tried .innerHtml. but it was not displaying css styles.